# tcp.h error with gcc 4.4.1

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 9.1 which comes with gcc 4.4.1 and I have a problem compiling my application:

```
/usr/include/linux/tcp.h:72: error: ‘__u32 __fswab32(__u32)’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
```

lines in cp.h causing errors:

```
     ...
enum { 
    TCP_FLAG_CWR = __cpu_to_be32(0x00800000),
    TCP_FLAG_ECE = __cpu_to_be32(0x00400000),
    TCP_FLAG_URG = __cpu_to_be32(0x00200000),
    TCP_FLAG_ACK = __cpu_to_be32(0x00100000),
     ...
```

Any ideas what can be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

include netinet/tcp.h instead.